# Ada compiler for Arm processors

Tags: compiler-construction, arm, ada

Does Anyone know an Ada compiler for Arm processors? 
I searched the web for hours and couldn't find one.
Thanks,
Yony.

Answer (score 12):

There is a [GNAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNAT) ada compiler, which can be used for ARM. For example, there is debian (linux) package of GNAT for ARMel:  http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/gnat

There is even version of GNAT from ARM's partner AdaCore, named GNAT Pro: http://www.arm.com/community/partners/display_product/rw/ProductId/5620/

IBM Rational Ada Embedded works only for MIPS, M68K, x86, RH-32, may be SPARC.

Irvine ICC Ada works only for x86; sparc; TI DSP C62xx/C64xx/C67xx; PowerPC 5xx, 6xx, 7xx; Intel i960; Intel i960; ADSP-210x0 SHARC DSP.

Green Hills Ada95 works only for: Power, 68k, CPU32, MIPS, x86, SPARC  [(docs)](http://www.ghs.com/products/ada_optimizing_compilers.html)

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of threads in `comp.lang.ada` that talk about this. IIRC there are several possibilities with different degrees of support.

It's unfortunate that in the Ada world ARM stands primarily for Ada Reference Manual, which can obstruct a bit your search, but here are a couple of threads I could quickly locate. Before listing them, to make the answer self-contained to a point, an ancient (but still valid, I guess) option is to use RTEMS. A recent effort is gnatdroid (check www.dragonlace.net ). I have no personal experience with either of them. I think I'm still missing a second recent project targeting Android, but I cannot remember nor locate it right now.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.ada/dUEvFLDEOi0

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.ada/c1YOG9jRvas

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.ada/8UyIPO6te6M

Answer (score 4):

There is GNATDroid, which primarily targets Android on ARM:

http://www.dragonlace.net/gnataux/armv7/

Maybe you can use this as basis for ARM stuff.